# How to load data from Azure Data Lake to Microsoft Lakehouse using Notebooks?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, azure-data-lake, data-lakehouse, microsoft-fabric

Here's my situation:

I have a storage in my Azure account that contains my tables from Dynamics 365 F&O and I have a JSON file with the column's name and type.
This is the 'header' file and i have another csv file (can it be 1 or more csv to the same table) with the data.

So, i need to combine these 2 for each table, and then load it to my Fabric Lakehouse.
So far, i'm trying to do this using this code:

```py
import json
import os

def get_cdm_files(directory_path):
    cdm_files = []

    for root, diers, files in os.walk(directory_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.cdm.json'):
                cdm_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
  
    return cdm_files

def load_table_cdm_file(cdm_file_path):
    with open(cdm_file_path.replace("abfss://rootfoldername@datalakename.dfs.core.windows.net/", "/dbfs/mnt/dynamics/")) as f:
        cdm_json = json.load(f)

    colss = []
    for item in cdm_json['definitions'][0]['hasAttributes']:
        colss.append(item["name"])
  
    return spark.read.csv(cdm_file_path.replace("cdm.json", ".csv"), header=False, inferSchema=True)

def load_all_tables(cdm_files):
    tables = {}

    for cdm_file in cdm_files:
        table_name = cdm_file.split("/")[-1].replace(".cdm.json", "").lower()
        tables[table_name] = load_table_cdm_file(cdm_file)
    
    return tables

def write_table_delta(table_name, table_df):
    spark.sql(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Lakehousename.Dynamics365_{table_name}")
    table_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").saveAsTable(f"Dynamics365_{table_name}")

def main():
    cdm_files = get_cdm_files("abfss://rootfoldername@datalakename.dfs.core.windows.net/domainname.operations.dynamics.com/Tables/")
    
    if "TABLENAME1.cdm.json" in cdm_files:
        cdm_files.remove("abfss://rootfoldername@datalakename.dfs.core.windows.net/domainname.operations.dynamics.com/Tables/Custom/TABLENAME1.cdm.json")
    
    if "TABLENAME2.cdm.json" in cdm_files:
        cdm_files.remove("abfss://rootfoldername@datalakename.dfs.core.windows.net/domainname.operations.dynamics.com/Tables/Custom/TABLENAME2.cdm.json")
    
    if "TABLE3.cdm.json" in cdm_files:
        cdm_files.remove("abfss://rootfoldername@datalakename.dfs.core.windows.net/domainname.operations.dynamics.com/Tables/Custom/TABLE3.cdm.json")

    tables = load_all_tables(cdm_files)

    for table_name, table_df in tables.items():
        write_table_delta(table_name, table_df)
```

I tried looking for guides but as it's a new thing isn't there much to search for, even the AI could help at all.

Comment: Have you looked into the CDMUtil solution by Microsoft? https://github.com/microsoft/Dynamics-365-FastTrack-Implementation-Assets/tree/master/Analytics/CDMUtilSolution . However, it was originally intended for Azure Synapse. In my view, it should work for Lake Database because we can connect to LakeDatabase using SQL Endpoint and that is all needed for CDMUtil to work. Give it a shot. I am using the CDMUtil console App for Azure Synapse serverless SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Alter each of your functions as below.

**get_cdm_files**

```
import json
import os

def get_cdm_files(directory_path):
    cdm_files = []

    for root, diers, files in os.walk(directory_path.replace("abfss://data@jadls2.dfs.core.windows.net/", "/dbfs/mnt/dynamics/")):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.cdm.json'):
                cdm_files.append(os.path.join(root.replace( "/dbfs/mnt/dynamics/","abfss://data@jadls2.dfs.core.windows.net/"), file))
  
    return cdm_files
```

will get `.cdm.json` files.

[image]

Next,

**load_table_cdm_file**

For reading csv files using the schema in json files.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField,StructType,StringType,DoubleType,IntegerType

data_type_mapping = {
        "string": StringType(),
        "integer": IntegerType(),
        "double": DoubleType(),
        # Add more mappings as needed
    }

def load_table_cdm_file(cdm_file_path):
    with open(cdm_file_path.replace("abfss://data@jadls2.dfs.core.windows.net/", "/dbfs/mnt/dynamics/")) as f:
        cdm_json = json.load(f)

    columns = [StructField(item["name"], data_type_mapping.get(item["type"],StringType()), True) for item in cdm_json['definitions'][0]['hasAttributes']]
    schema = StructType(columns)
    print(schema)
    df = spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).load(cdm_file_path.replace("cdm.json", "csv"), header=False)
    return df
```

[image]

There is no change in **load_all_tables** keep it has it is.
Now writing the table to lakehouse, if you are using
notebook in lakehouse itself the **write_table_delta**
function works fine.

Or

if you are using notebook in databricks use below code to write.
Before running this code make sure to check mark
**Enable credential passthrough for user-level data access** under **Advanced option**.

[image]

Copy `abfss` path to the lakehouse table.

[image]

[image]

Go to properties of the table and copy the path, it is something similar to below one.

`abfss://<kjfneldqw>@msit-onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/<6382ey398e>/Tables`

**write_table_delta**

```
lakehouse_table_path="abfss_path" #your_abfss_path_to_lakehouse_table
def write_table_delta(table_name, table_df):
    table_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").save(f"{lakehouse_table_path}/Dynamics365_{table_name}")
```

Now run your main code.

```
cdm_files = get_cdm_files("abfss://data@jadls2.dfs.core.windows.net/domainname.operations.dynamics.com/Tables/")
print(cdm_files)
tables = load_all_tables(cdm_files)
print(tables)
for table_name, table_df in tables.items():
    write_table_delta(table_name, table_df)
```

Output:

[image]

and in lakehouse.

[image]

Again you can read this table using `spark.read.format("delta").load("abfss_path")`
providing lakehouse abfss table path.

Comment: hello Jayashankar, thanks for the help, but still the code doenst affect anything. I've seen that you tested on databricks notebook, and somehow there works, but i'm trying to do it inside fabric notebook. The code runs fine, but doesn't actually do anything, and i dont know exactly what's going wrong with it..

Comment: Table is not creating?
There the you need to use correct mount path according to its filesystem. In databricks it is `/dbfs/mnt/dynamics/` but in fabric notebook it will be something like `/synfs/<some_id>/mnt/dynamics`.